# Value wrapped twice in JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee

I just want to implement a simple REST-Interface and got a problem passing a parameter to a sub resource:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}/status2")
public void updateStatus2(@PathParam("id") long id, JsonObject status) {
        System.out.println(status);
}
```

Passing a value via curl:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/todo/resources/todos/6/status2 -d '{"status":true}'
```

stdout gives me the string (which is correct and works): `{"status":true}`

---

Now I do the same in the unit test:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/todo/resources/todos");

// Todo is a simple POJO just a few strings, value types, getter and setters.
Todo todo = new Todo("foobar0", "foobar1", 1);

// I persist the Todo via post. 
URI createdTodoUri = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.json(todo));

// Create a new object to to pass it via put.
JsonObject statusObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("status", true).build();

// Send the JsonObject.
client.target(createdTodoUri).path("/status2").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).put(Entity.json(statusObject));
```

Now stdou prints this and I don't understand why: `{"status":{"valueType":"TRUE"}}`

---

As requested the class Todo.java:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String caption;
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    private boolean done;

    public Todo() {}

    public Todo(String caption, String description, int priority) {
        this.caption = caption;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getCaption() { return caption; }

    public void setCaption(String caption) { this.caption = caption; }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }

    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }

    public int getPriority() { return priority; }

    public void setPriority(int priority) { this.priority = priority; }

    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public boolean isDone() { return done; }

    public void setDone(boolean status) { this.done = status; }
}
```

---

Why is there a difference and what do I have to change so my unit test works?

Comment: You can show us the definition of the ``Todo`` class please ?

Comment: I added the requested class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write `statusObject` to Json using `JsonWriter` instead of simply passing it directly into request. Passing it to request makes java to serialize its internal structure what is not the same.

Imho it would be better to use either simple boolean atribute or POJO both on server and on client (test) site.